# LDAP Authentication using a technical user

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

In my organization we had a request to implement LDAP authentication for a new application. The problem we faced was that CN used to connect to active directory is different that the sAMAccountName.

sAMAccountName was the username given to user by the organization while cn was something like `lastName, firstName [Intern]`.

To solve this problem we decided to use a technical user to retrieve the cn from sAMAccountName and then try to authenticate the user using cn and password, the code looked like:

```
InitialDirContext initialDirContext = new InitialDirContext(initUserAuthenticationInfo(technicalUserCredentilas.Username, technicalUserCredentilas.Password))
searchResult =initialDirContext.search(AuthenticationHelper.DEFAULT_SEARCH_BASE, "(&(sAMAccountName=" + username + "))", searchCriteria)
userCNFromAD = searchResult.hasMore() ? "CN=" + (searchResult.nextElement().getAttributes().get("cn").get())
```

The problem is, whenever a failed login attemp for the user happen, Active directory is treating it as a failed login attemp for the technical user! and then after some time the technical user is always getting locked
I tried to close initialDirContext after getting user cn using initialDirContext.close() but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Would it be an option to simply use the technical user to retrieve the `CN` for a given `sAMAccountName` and then simply use the retrieved `CN` for login?

Comment: This is exactly what I did, my problem is when I am using the normal user info for login and this login is failing (wrong password for example) then this is considered as a failed login attemp for the technical user!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Directory can authenticate users with domain-and-user sAMAccountName or userPrincipalName values. If you have a single tree in a single forest, the username "sampleuser" in a domain called "domain.ccTLD" (legacy name "domain") can authenticate as "domain\sampleuser" or "sampleuser@domain.com" -- there's no need to figure out the actual distinguished name.

But for the flow you are using, which is what I use for LDAP authentication both to AD and to pure LDAP servers (OpenLDAP, Oracle Unified Directory, etc):

- Connect to the LDAP server Bind with the service account
- Search for the user with your "(&(sAMAccountName=...))" filter
- Retrieve the fully qualified DN (distinguishedName attribute value or returned
  object DN)
- Disconnect from the LDAP server.
- Connect to the LDAP server
- Bind with the retrieved fully qualified DN and user-supplied password
- (Optional: if you are performing authorization as well, verify group memberships as needed)
- Disconnect from the LDAP server

By separating the system account logon and search from the user logon and search, I've never seen a system account incorrectly locked.